# Handle Inheritancy with JHipster

Tags: java, inheritance, jhipster, jdl

Please I would like to know if it is possible to use inheritancy while modeling class diagram with JDL language in JHipster. They did not mention this aspect in the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's not possible in JDL, you have to modify manually generated code.